# Are there lots of various Empirical distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, terminology

Chapter 3 of [the deeplearningbook](https://deeplearningbook.org) gives this formula for "Empirical distribution"

\begin{equation}
\hat{p}(x) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \delta(x - x^{(i)}) \tag{3.28}
\end{equation}

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) gives this formula for "Empirical distribution"

${\displaystyle {\widehat {F}}_{n}(t)={\frac {{\mbox{number of elements in the sample}}\leq t}{n}}={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\mathbf {1} _{X_{i}\leq t}}$

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/427754/257182) talks a lot different from above without giving a formula, which gives a feeling the "Empirical" in Empirical distribution is literally general.

So, are there lots of various Empirical distribution?

Comment: Those first 2 are equivalent btw.

Comment: Your final two links are to the same post.  Your second expression is a definition of the [empirical cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) mentioned there, and the first expression is an attempt to differentiate it

Comment: Empirical distribution is in essence the "easiest" approximation of a random variable. Glivenko-Cantelli theorem gives a precise statement for when the approximation is legitimate. I wouldn't view the empirical distribution as interesting on its own, but interesting for approximations.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking Thanks for your comments. Consider the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a random variable, besides the empirical CDF, what are other commonly used estimator?

Comment: @whnlp I'm not a statistician so I cannot answer that with confidence.