# Does the function $u_{\alpha}(x)$ has a canonical name? What is the derivative of it at $\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$?

Tags: derivatives, step-function

I am learning this [post](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_2_delta_function.php) to understand this [claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3362877/660389)

> the derivative of a step function is the Dirac delta.

Consider the unit step function u(x) defined by

\begin{equation}
     \hspace{50pt}
              u(x) = \left\{
              \begin{array}{l l}
                1  &  \quad  x \geq 0 \\
                0 &  \quad \text{otherwise}
              \end{array} \right.
     \hspace{50pt} (4.8)
            \end{equation}

This function has a jump at x=0. Let us remove the jump and define, for any α>0, the function $u_α$ as
\begin{equation}
             \nonumber u_{\alpha}(x) = \left\{
              \begin{array}{l l}
                1  &  \quad   x > \frac{\alpha}{2} \\
                \frac{1}{\alpha} (x+\frac{\alpha}{2})  &   \quad  -\frac{\alpha}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\alpha}{2} \\
                0 &  \quad x < -\frac{\alpha}{2}
              \end{array} \right.
            \end{equation}

$u_{\alpha}(x)$ is a continuous function. Now let us define the function $\delta_{\alpha}(x)$ as the derivative of $u_{\alpha}(x)$ wherever it exists.

\begin{equation}
             \nonumber \delta_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{ d u_{\alpha}(x)}{dx} = \left\{
              \begin{array}{l l}
                \frac{1}{\alpha}  &  \quad  |x| < \frac{\alpha}{2}   \\
                0 &  \quad |x| > \frac{\alpha}{2}
              \end{array} \right.
            \end{equation}

## question

1. Does the function $u_{\alpha}(x)$ has a canonical name?
2. Is the function above not differentiable at $\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$

or

It doesn't matter what the derivative of $u_{\alpha}(x)$ at $\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$ is

or

the derivative of $u_{\alpha}(x)$ at $\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$ is also $\dfrac{1}{a}$ ?

Comment: The derivative is piecewise constant, with two discontinuities.  At those two points it has a left-derivative and a right-derivative, which are not equal.